# routemapping with extra parameters c# net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

In the routeattribute of controller I want to add more parameters for my rest api, if possible. And how can I get/use them when running the code.

The default route of a controller looks like.

[Route("api/[controller]")]

and I want to have do like

[Route("api/[language]/[controller]")]

And then pass the language value to next layer.
So I can have a default language or user can override it if he wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an example of language handling that damienbod have done regarding language handling in net core api. Good example for this question with language in route and extra parameters.

https://github.com/damienbod/AspNetCoreLocalization

Answer (score 0):

You can set a common parameter for an entire controller by using the [RoutePrefix] attribute:

Please find the below example containing TestController having attribute [RoutePrefix] and method as "GetDetails".

```
[RoutePrefix("api/{language}/test")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [Route("GetDetails")]
    public string GetDetails(string language)
    {
        // Use language string parameter here.
        return language;
    }
}
```

Here RoutePrefix contains the parameter {language} which is applicable for all the methods. Use a tilde (~) on the method attribute to override the route prefix.

For example - [Route("~/api/test/GetAllDetails")]

Comment: Thanks, yes that I know but is there away of getting the values without setting them on each method. like http://localhost:62564/api/test/Hindi/GetDetails

Comment: You can set a common attribute for an entire controller by using the [RoutePrefix] attribute:

Comment: Thanks that works with some modifications for net core. The RoutePrefix doeas not exist. It is just Route above the class name and the input are the template. The attribute looks like [Route("api/{language}/[controller]")] and  then I can use language as in parameter if I need to use it exacly that you have done in your example.

Comment: RoutePrefix is present in Web-API 2.

Comment: Yes but as I said RoutePrefix should be Route in net core and [HttpGet] on method